# Devise Rspec undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I've scoured SO and no one else's results seem to work for me:

I have a `ControllerHelper` method for my Spec based off what was suggested for Devise:

```
def login_existing_user
  @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  company = FactoryGirl.create(:company)
  user.company_id = company.id
  sign_in user
end
```

I am also creating a `Company` in this method since that's step 2 of the sign up process for a user to be able to get my authenticated homepage.

At this point, I'm just trying to log the user in with my `ScansControllerSpec`:

```
RSpec.describe ScansController, type: :controller do

  before(:all) do
    login_existing_user
    @device = build(:device)
  end

  describe "GET #create" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :create, :device_id => @device.id
      puts response
      # expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end

  ....
end
```

But I'm getting this for every one of my CRUD method RSpecs:

```
1) ScansController GET #create returns http success
     Failure/Error: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/support/controller_helpers.rb:15:in `login_existing_user'
     # ./spec/controllers/scans_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

As other posts have suggested, I am including the `Devise::TestHelpers` in my `rails_helper.rb` file.  I've also included my `ControllerHelpers`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.include ControllerHelpers, type: :controller

  config.after do
    Warden.test_reset!
  end
end
```

In the end, I need to be able to log a user in to test that protected controller methods work.  I'm not sure if this is an association problem, so I'll add that a user has to have a `company`, and a company has to have a `subscription` in order to successfully log in.

... but I can't even get that far since this error is holding me back.

Comment: controller tests don't run through an actual request, if you want access to the `request` object (no `@`) then you ned to make these request specs.

Comment: @Anthony Sorry, being new to testing I don't quite follow.  So, how do I go about testing all of my protected controller methods?  I have Devise's `before_action :authenticate_user!` in my `application_controller.rb`, which lead me to believe I needed to mimic a logged in user.

Comment: Also, If I take out `login_existing_user` from my tests, I get redirected to my login page.

Comment: Dumb question. Do you require `rails_helper` or `spec_helper` in your `ScansControllerSpec`?

Comment: @VAD yes, I have `require 'rails_helper'` at the very top.

Comment: Hard to answer on an SO comment but look here for specific examples: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs

Comment: @Anthony gotcha.. made the change, still the same error referencing this line in my code now: `allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_return(user)`.  Just doesn't seem to like the `env`

Comment: @Godzilla74 do you find the solution im facing the same error in requests_spec.rb because I'm doing the same thing as you did

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to have gotten past this issue by following: http://willschenk.com/setting-up-testing/